# Drupal - How to apply security patches via composer?

Tags: security, drupal, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8.6.7. Now I am getting below message.

> There is a security update available for your version of Drupal. To
>   ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! See
>   the available updates page for more information.

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.8.1

[image]

How to apply above security patches although not using 8.8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states :

> Versions of Drupal 8 prior to 8.7.x are end-of-life and do not receive
>   security coverage.

The only solution to apply these patches is to upgrade core :

- If you are using Drupal 7.x, upgrade to [Drupal 7.69](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/7.69).
- If you are using **Drupal 8.7.x or below, upgrade to [Drupal 8.7.11](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.7.11)**.
- If you are using Drupal 8.8.x, upgrade to [Drupal 8.8.1](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.8.1).

Comment: That document I have already seen. How to apply patches via Composer?

Comment: oh I see.. it's a problem with the word "upgrade" itself, right ?

Comment: Nope. Question is can I put same version 8.6.7 and apply security patches? or required to upgrade to 8.7.11?

Comment: So the answer is no you can't, these patches only apply for upgraded core.

Comment: Noted. Stuck over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59527569/drupal-upgrade-from-8-6-7-to-8-8-1. How can I update to specific version

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3079333#comment-13415084 - This helps to upgrade to 8.7.11 :)